# Userspace code not calling framebuffer write cb

Tags: linux-kernel, framebuffer

I have written a custom QEMU framebuffer device.  In support of this I also wrote a framebuffer driver for Linux.  `cat /dev/urandom > /dev/fb0` works wonderfully and calls my fb_write callback (nonstandard layout, can't be mmap'ed). However my attempt at a userspace application refuses to work.

I have opened `/dev/fb0` with `fopen([filename], "rwb");` and a non-null pointer is returned.  But when I go to write to it with fwrite, although the FILE* is still non-null, an error is returned and perror prints "Bad File descriptor."  Any ideas?

Comment: Try `posix` I/O. `open[/dev/fb0,O_WRDONLY)`. Also note that `"rwb"` is invalid mode for `fopen` (you meant `"r+"`) and the `b` is ignored on posix systems.

Comment: This was correct.  Imagine writing a QEMU device and a kernel module just to get hung up on open vs fopen.  Feel free to upgrade this to answer if you want the internet points.